# Make a transition effect in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I am really new to Twitter Bootstrap (in my second hour of learning it :)

I want to make a sliding transition effect like this: http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/317_coming_soon/demo/index.html

How do I go about doing this in Twitter Bootstrap. My problem is that I do not how to work the transitions. Any code would be valuable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don’t use Twitter Bootstrap; use [the same CSS framework](http://daneden.me/animate/) as the one you mention on the Amazon page.

Look at [the documentation](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) for much more informations on how to use it. It says:

> To use animate.css in your website, simply drop the stylesheet into your document's `<head>`, and add the class `animated` to an element, along with any of the animation names. That's it! You've got a CSS animated element. Super!

Comment: Thanks - I thought nobody would answer. That is what I ended up doing.